# Suggestions to improve Task responsiveness?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have an application which downloads a single file in 4 different segments (each segment is a different long running task) and serializes the progress at periodic intervals.

When the serialize takes place on a 2 core machine the process will block for 3-10 seconds and then complete. Once this blocking behavior has happened the first time it will never happen again. The 2nd to (n) calls to serialize execute immediately without a hitch. It appears that during the first call blocking the framework did some Task/Threading optimization that prevents the blocking behavior form occurring again.

Does anyone have any insight into this optimization and if it is possible to do this type of optimization at initialization to avoid the blocking behavior all together?

Here is some pseudo code to help describe the situation:

```
class Download
{
    private DownloadSegment[] _downloadSegments = new DownloadSegment[4];

    public void StartDownload()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            _downloadSegments[i] = new DownloadSegment();
            _downloadSegments[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void Serialize()
    {
        try
        {        
            //enter lock so the code does not serilize the progress while 
            //writing new downloaded info at the same time
            foreach(DownloadSegment segment in _downloadSegments)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(segment.SyncRoot);
            }

            //code to serialize the progress
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (DownloadSegment segment in _downloadSegments)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(segment.SyncRoot);
            }
        }

    }
}

class DownloadSegment
{
    public object SyncRoot = new object();

    public void Start()
    {
        Task downloadTask = new Task(
            () =>
                {
                    //download code
                    lock (SyncRoot)
                    {
                        //wirte to disk code
                    }                        
                },
        new CancellationToken(),
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        downloadTask.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using .net 4.5 or willing to use the [async targeting pack for 4.0](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)? It opens up some options.

Comment: Unfortunately I am restricted to .Net 4 but I do have the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package installed and I am actively using it in other areas of the application.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code shown. Replace the places you commented out with calls to Thread.Sleep to assure that the problem is not with the code not shown here. Does the "hitch" still occur?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion usr. Putting in a sleep will not cause the issue. The issue appears to be dependent on the download code having an open file stream. The serialize code will obtain locks on the first 2 segments immediately while the last 2 will stick at the file stream flush statement for a few seconds every single time. Once it has happened once it never happens again.

I will try to put together a better example that will actually cause the issue.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the problem only occurs when the CPU cores < Number of segments. If it is run on a very fast machine the "hitch" resolves so fast it is not really noticeable, but a slower dual core with 4 segments the "hitch" lasts a few seconds.

Comment: I then recommend that you redesign the locking so that disk IO is not done under a lock (imagine waiting 30s for a broken network drive). You can use multiple FileStreams for the same file which is a strategy for thread safety (each segment can open one stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions usr. It turns out it was the filestream write causing the problem.

It turns out that when you use FileStream.SetLength() to allocate file space for a large file and then seek to a section deep inside that file, once you start writing at that position in the file the sparse file space will be "backfilled" and this can be slow. The locks I have in the code simply expose the problem by making the unblocked segments wait on the ones that are busy.

I will be posting a separate question to see if there is a more efficient way to write/create these files.